# jpype startJVM crashes ipython notebook

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jpype

I'm trying to use JPype within ipython notebook in order to use JIDT (I don't know Java). I'm following the instructions here: https://code.google.com/p/information-dynamics-toolkit/wiki/PythonExamples.

I import jpype and start the java virtual machine with:

```
from jpype import *
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath())
```

This makes the ipython notebook kernel crash due to the following error:

```
python(490,0x7fff7a99e310) malloc: *** error for object 0x104d90720: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

However, it works fine in the ipython shell.

How can I know where the error comes from and how can I fix it?

I use:
OSX 10.9.5
Python 2.7.10,Anaconda 2.2.0,IPython 3.1.0

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the C compiler used to install JPype. Try setting C compiler to clang and install JPype like this:

```
$env CC=clang python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hi any reason why this could be the cause? I've a similar situation running in a windows environment.